# What is wrong with the way I write and or read the EEPROM adresses?

Tags: c++, esp32, eeprom

Consider:

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>

byte guifactor1 = 1;
byte guifactor2 = 2;
byte guifactor3 = 3;
byte guifactor4 = 4;
byte guifactorgas = 5;
byte guifactorwater = 6;

volatile unsigned long count1factor;
volatile unsigned long count2factor;
volatile unsigned long count3factor;
volatile unsigned long count4factor;
volatile unsigned long countgasfactor;
volatile unsigned long countwaterfactor;

void loop(){
if (guifactor1 > -1){
    EEPROM.write(1, guifactor1);
    EEPROM.commit();
    count1factor = EEPROM.read(1);
    Serial.println(count1factor);
  }

  if (guifactor2 > -1){
    EEPROM.write(2, guifactor2);
    EEPROM.commit();
    count2factor = EEPROM.read(2);
    Serial.println(count2factor);
  }

  if (guifactor3 > -1){
    EEPROM.write(3, guifactor3);
    EEPROM.commit();
    count3factor = EEPROM.read(3);
    Serial.println(count3factor);
  }

  if (guifactor4 > -1){
    EEPROM.write(4, guifactor4);
    EEPROM.commit();
    count4factor = EEPROM.read(4);
    Serial.println(count4factor);
  }

  if (guifactorgas > -1){
    EEPROM.write(5, guifactorgas);
    EEPROM.commit();
    countgasfactor = EEPROM.read(5);
    Serial.println(countgasfactor);
  }

  if (guifactor1 > -1){
    EEPROM.write(6, guifactorwater);
    EEPROM.commit();
    countwaterfactor = EEPROM.read(6);
    Serial.println(countwaterfactor);
  }
}

void setup(){

}
```

The problem I have with my code is that it either doesn’t write the value to the EEPROM or it doesn’t read the value as it doesn’t print anything to the monitor.

I expected to read 1 2 3 4 5 6 from the monitor as I write the bytes to the EEPROM and then transfer the value to the *unsigned long* and print the variable.

Comment: What problem do you actually have? You didn't include any problem description. From your code I would say: `guifactor1` and its siblings will be implicitly initialized with zero (since they are global and you don't explicitly initialize them). Checking `guifactor1 > -1` won't ever be true, since you initialized them to zero and don't change them anymore, and also they are `unsigned long`s, so they cannot ever carry a negative value. You should rethink the logic of your program.

Comment: What does it print to `Serial`?

Comment: Your problem description is still too vague. Please describe exactly what you expected the code to do and what is actually did. Provide the expected and actual output. And write a minimal compilable example code, that shows your problem. We cannot debug code that we cannot see

Comment: What is the sense behind the if statements? `guifactor1` and siblings still cannot ever be `-1`, since `byte` is the same as `unsigned char` which also cannot hold negative values. Also you still don't change these variables ever. So you won't see anything. The code inside the if statements is never reached

Comment: the question was about the reading and writing to the eeprom i have not given all of my code and it isnt finished i was just testing

Comment: If you are asking just about the code lines reading and writing the EEPROM, then the answer is "Nothing is wrong with it." The problem must be somewhere in the code that you refuse to show. And we just cannot help you with that. Our mind reading powers are limited.

Comment: the problem is solved

Comment: You know that EEPROMs are limited in the number of write operation, do you? As you're writing to EEPROM in loop without any delay, this code is one way to kill the EEPROM quite fast.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark the answer. Or if it does not answer your question, write an own. This site is to help many, not only you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call `Serial.begin()` in `setup()`.

As a side note, your `if` tests are useless. The compiler warns me that:

```
comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

**For reference**: the previous answer, valid for the initial question
where `guifactor1` and co. were all `unsigned long`.

---

The program does nothing because all the actions are conditioned on
tests such as

```cpp
if (guifactor1 > -1)
```

and these tests are always false. The reason they are false is because
arithmetic comparison operators such as `<` [perform *usual arithmetic
conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators) on their operands prior to doing the actual
comparison. Since `guifactor1` is `unsigned long`, and this type has a
higher conversion rank than `int` (the type of `-1`), the second operand
is implicitly converted to `unsigned long`, yielding `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: this is not my entire code. i didnt upload all of it because it could be a bit overwelming. i edited the code above so that the problem is a bit more clear i also changed the unsigned long to a byte.

Comment: @JayvandeWetering: Please, test the program you posted (not your original code, but the exact code that is in your question, as you just amended it) and make sure it does show the incorrect behavior.

Comment: i have tested the program i posted and it still either doesnt write or doesnt read from the eeprom

Comment: @JayvandeWetering: How do you know it doesn't write or doesn't read? Please update your question with the relevant details.

Comment: i think i updated the question enough so that it is clear what is expected and what is the actual output